# How to sign an APK with more than one certificate?

Tags: android, key

(I know this has been asked before but it's a different issue.)

I accidententley signed my market app with the debug.keystore I don't want to loose my progress on the Market.

So I signed my app with the debug.keystore so I can do this

Version 1.0 => Signed with Certificate A
Version 2.0 => Signed with Certificate A & B
Version 3.0 => Signed with Certificate B

Then I tried to issue the command

jarsigner -verbose -keystore private.keystore myapp.apk private

and I get the following error

jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compres
sed size (expected 2735 but got 2785 bytes)

Help!

Please check this at google you are badly mistaken why would I be here complaining if it didnt happen

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?fid=214674fe44ec7f0d00049bff172dfec9&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

> I accidententley signed my market app with the debug.keystore I don't want to loose my progress on the Market.

That is not possible. A debug key will not be accepted by the Android Market, in part because the lifetime of the certificate is too short.

Comment: Please check this http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?fid=214674fe44ec7f0d00049bff172dfec9&hl=en

Comment: Used Apk Maager auto compile, sign and zipalign script to do it. Please read the edit above.

Comment: @user583739: As I wrote, a debug key will not be accepted by the Android Market, in part because the lifetime of the certificate is too short. I believe that you are mistaken in terms of what keystore you were originally using.

Comment: It must be some generic andriod key google never accounted for. In any case the solution is what maters now.

Comment: Here is the error "Market does not accept apks signed with certificates issued by Android team. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years."

Comment: If you search Google you only get results for with debug certificate.

Comment: "The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version"

Comment: @user583739: With respect to your problem, AFAIK, you are just out of luck. Create a new app, in a new package, with the new signing key.